# Issues with Client size function

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a Windows Form and struggling to draw lines that are centered, can I get some help with the solution for this. Thank you.

```
Dim iFormHeight As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Height
Dim iFormWidth As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Width
Dim centreX As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2
Dim centreY As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Height \ 2
Dim compteur As Integer = 0
Dim x1 As Integer = centreX - 50
Dim y1 As Integer = centreY - 50
Dim x2 As Integer = centreX + 50
Dim y2 As Integer = centreY + 50
Dim g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
Dim pen1 As New Pen(Color.Red)

Private Sub Form3_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, y1, x1, y1)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x1, 0, x1, y1)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x2, y1, x2, 0)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x2, y1, iFormWidth, y1)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, y2, x1, y2)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x1, y2, x1, iFormHeight)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x2, y2, x2, iFormHeight)
    g.DrawLine(pen1, x2, y2, iFormWidth, y2)
    pen1.Dispose()
    g.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, MyBase.Resize
    hautgauche.Location = New Point(x1 - basdroit.Width, y1 - basdroit.Height)
    basdroit.Location = New Point(x2, y2)
    hautdroit.Location = New Point(x2, y1 - basdroit.Width)
    basgauche.Location = New Point(x1 - basdroit.Height, y2)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLKA.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yj5d.png)

Comment: It's `(ClientSize.Width / 2) - ([Intersection] / 2)`, the same in Y. Assuming `[Intersection]` is 1/3 of the shortest dimension of the Client Rectangle, then `[Intersection] = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height) / 3` (or divide by 6 and subtract this measure). Or use a fixed value, I'm not sure what result you're expecting. These calculations are either performed in the `Paint` event or, partially, in the `Resize` event -- I assume you don't actually want to distort the bitmaps -- Specify how the size of the intersection should be, in your view -- What's the Timer for?

Comment: This thing: `Dim g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()` must be removed. The `PaintEventArgs` object provides the Graphics object you need to use -- The `Pen` is declared as a Field, you dispose of it when the Form closes, not in the `Paint` event. Or you declare a new one in the `Paint` event, in case the color should change (using a custom Property, maybe)

Comment: Thank you Jimi for the help, i will work on fixing the issue based on this.